# Wireless 7260 AC won't connect as AC

Tags: wireless, 17.04, intel-wireless

My wifi works fine, except that I can not connect to as AC.
I have multiple AC routers but I can't get my ubuntu machine with an Intel 7260 Wifi Chipset to connect at an AC bit rate.

I have tried 16.04, 16.10 and now 17.04

Wireless Script Output

http://paste.ubuntu.com/24846895/

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please edit your question to add the extra script output, not post it as an answer.

Comment: It's too long for the sites body length validation

Comment: You can use paste.ubuntu.com for long outputs. Regarding your speed, I wouldn't trust the tool output and check the actual speed with iperf instead. You have connected to a 5Ghz network which is good. Now start `iperf3 -s` on one node (say, your openwrt router) and `iperf -c <router-ip>` on your laptop. This will give you the actual numbers for a TCP workload. You can also do `iperf3 -c --udp -b 1000M <router-ip>` to test UDP and compare. You won't get 802.11ac peak rates as they depend on the range to AP, obstacles in the way and other factors.

Comment: Im using a file-transfer to test and comparing to other machines that are connected via AC